# Rxswift What difference between Observable.of and Observable<String>.create

Tags: rx-swift

I'm a newbie in rxSwift. I found some difference when create Observable by 
`Observable.of` and `Observable<String>.create`

```
    Observable<String>.create { observer in

    observer.onNext("1")

    observer.onNext("2")

    return Disposables.create()
    }.take(3).toArray().subscribe(onNext: { (item) in
        print(item)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Not emitted util received at least 3 event. In this way observer never emitted.
But with:

```
    Observable.of("1", "2")
    // 2
    .take(3).toArray()
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print($0) })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

But when i create by this way.
Observer always emitted even if i just have 2 elements.
I don't known what difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that `of` sends a completed event as well. You can check the example below, the second "completed" will not be called.

You have to write `observer.onCompleted()` after `observer.onNext("2")` it order to have the same logic.

```
Observable.of("1", "2").subscribe(onCompleted: {
    print("completed")
})

Observable<String>.create { observer in
        observer.onNext("1")
        observer.onNext("2")
        return Disposables.create()
    }
    .subscribe(onCompleted: {
        print("completed")
    })
```