# How can I wrap an async function with an Observable

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have an async function that currently looks something like this

```
func startLoginFlow() {
    IdentityProvider.shared.login { success, error in
        // on success a user has completed authentication
        if success {
            delegate?.userIsAuthenticated()
        }


        // on error something wen't wrong
        ....
    }
}
```

Essentially on success a delegate method is called and some action takes place as a result.

I'd like to wrap this as an observable instead. I do not have the option refactoring `IdentityProvider.shared.login`.

I essentially just need the observable to emit so I can subscribe and take action elsewhere using `onNext`.

I am currently doing the following

```
  func startLoginFlow() -> Observable<Void> {
        return Observable.create { [weak self] observable in
            IdentityProvider.shared.login { success, error in
                if success {
                    observable.onNext(Void())
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

Is this the best way to do this? I wasn't sure if I should use `Observable.of` and subscribe to the result of  `IdentityProvider.shared.login`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I create Observables as well. The only thing I would note is to add in the `errors` so you can handle your observables when it errors out, and the `completion`, as well, to signal that your observable is complete.

```swift
func startLoginFlow() -> Observable<Void> {
        return Observable.create { [weak self] observable in
            IdentityProvider.shared.login { success, error in
                if success {
                    observable.onNext(())
                    observable.onCompleted()
                } else {
                    observable.onError(error)
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

`Observable.of`'s work in this case as well. It just emits the `completed` method. You can test this out yourself, if you were trying to create an `Observable<String>`, with both methods.

I find that doing `Observable.create` is beneficial here as you're doing network requests and that you can control how you want your observables to error, fail, or be completed.

Someone here gave a pretty good example as well:

[Rxswift What difference between Observable.of and Observable<String>.create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885948/rxswift-what-difference-between-observable-of-and-observablestring-create)

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate that